# How can I format my Google calendar like the "Days of the Year" calendar?

Tags: google-calendar, google-api

Is there any way to format my calendar entries like the "Days of the Year" calendar does? (Shown here, the "40" in the top corner.)

[image]

I am adding events to the calendar using the Calendar API using `myCalendar.createAllDayEvent('Title', myDate)`.

I can't find any information in the API documentation that seems to relate to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that Google Calendar API version 3 exposes "gadgets".  That's what needs to be used to format entries as described here.

See: [Calendar Event Gadgets](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/gadgets/event/)